# Touch event on FrameLayout

Tags: android, events, touch, android-framelayout

I have a layout like this:

- RelativeLayout

  - FrameLayout

    - Fragment (google maps layer)
  - Checkbox
  - ... other buttons and stuff

Now I want to capture touch events on the `FrameLayout` when the `Checkbox` is checked. I got it working with `dispatchTouchEvent` instead of `onTouch`, but then the problem is that I also get touch response when I press the Checkbox button. I want to exclude it but I can't figure out how it works...

Do I need to create a new class or something?

This is my code, stripped a lot:

```
public class Main extends Activity implements LocationListener, OnTouchListener {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.mapFrame);
    frame.setOnTouchListener((OnTouchListener) this);
  }

  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

    //doing things

    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
public class Main extends Activity implements LocationListener, OnTouchListener {

  private FrameLayout mFrame;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.mapFrame);
    mFrame.setOnTouchListener(this);
  }

  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

    if(mFrame == v) {

      // do things

      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```